# How to resolve background-image url inside css file while using azure blob storage

Tags: css, azure

Does anybody knows while using azure blob storage to store css file , how to handler the image url inside css file like 'background-image: url(../images/test.jpg)' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are in the same container as the CSS, but in another "subfolder", then you can use a relative URL like `background-image: url("../images/test.jpg");`.
If they are anywhere else, better use an absolute URL like `background-image: url("http://www.yuorsite.com/images/test.jpg");`

Comment: thanks, i do not know the relative url also works on blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file name in quotes **" "** `background-image: url("../images/test.jpg");`